# ZOC Terminal:text has been cut halfway down the page

Tags: linux, shell, terminal

I work with ZOC terminal installed at windows 7 in order to communicate with device that has Linux operating system [zoc picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i3zzl.jpg).
The communication via terminal works great but recently the text has been cut halfway down the page.
attached picture .

Answer (score 1):

The picture shows 24 lines.  You can get this behavior if your terminal description sets scrolling margins to 24 lines — as some might do, when initializing the terminal if the application assumes that the screen has 24 lines.

Since ZOC could be connecting via a serial port, that may not allow *negotiations about window size* ([NAWS](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1073.txt)).  You might then see that `stty -a` shows 24 lines in its output.  ZOC is said to emulate a VT100; you can usually adjust its notion of screensize either directory (using `stty`) or using the [`resize`](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/manpage/resize.html) program (which calls the same system functions as [`stty`](http://www.skrenta.com/rt/man/stty.1.html) as a side-effect).

Answer (score 0):

`Alt+y` solved the issue I had..